# Excel VBA Function to Do Loop And Test Criteria

Tags: vba, loops, excel

**Background information**:
I am trying to test the future dates to check if they fall on Monday, Wednesday or Saturday. If the dates falls on one of the three criteria, the date is returned into the cell. I managed to get this part down.

**Problem**: I would like the function to automatically loop for another 45 days instead of only referencing from the first date.

**Questions**:

- Is there a more efficient way or neater way to write the code?
- Is it possible to perform loop in functions? Is yes, could you show and explain
- What are other possible methods? I am looking at expanding my knowledge, please share :)

Thank you for your time!

```
Public Function AFPSECONDOFFDAY(NextOffDay As Date) As String
Dim ans As String, dayCount As Integer, n As Integer

n = 2

' This statement returns the date into the cell if it is Monday, Wednesday or Saturday

If Format(NextOffDay + 2, "w", vbMonday) = 1 _
Or Format(NextOffDay + 2, "w", vbMonday) = 3 _
Or Format(NextOffDay + 2, "w", vbMonday) = 6 Then
' would like it to continue for another 45 days instead 
' of stopping after + 2 days
    AFPSECONDOFFDAY = NextOffDay + 2

Else
    'If the date does not meet the criteria, I would like it to _
    skip and do the next date. So that cells will be filled simultaneously.
    AFPSECONDOFFDAY = ""

End If

End Function
```

Comment: Getting this to loop is the easy part. How would you like this information to be returned? Do you want all the dates returned to the cell that this is entered into?

Comment: Please make it offset to the right continuously till the end. First cell, second cell, and onwards :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would nest the function in a subprocedure. The below loops through 45 days (NextOffDay included in those 45) and writes each date that falls on a Mon, Wed or Fri to the next open cell in row 1 of the first worksheet in the workbook the code is written in.

```
Public Function AFPSECONDOFFDAY(NextOffDay As Date) As String
Dim ans As String, dayCount As Integer, n As Integer

n = 2 

' This statement returns the date into the cell if it is Monday, Wednesday     or Saturday

If Format(NextOffDay + 2, "w", vbMonday) = 1 _
Or Format(NextOffDay + 2, "w", vbMonday) = 3 _
Or Format(NextOffDay + 2, "w", vbMonday) = 6 Then
' would like it to continue for another 45 days instead 
' of stopping after + 2 days
    AFPSECONDOFFDAY = NextOffDay + 2

Else
    'If the date does not meet the criteria, I would like it to _
    skip and do the next date. So that cells will be filled simultaneously.
    AFPSECONDOFFDAY = ""

End If

End Function

Sub Func_Loop()
Dim NextOffDay as Date
Dim i as Integer

Call Different_Sub 'You simply write Call and the name of the sub procedure.
                   'If it is in a different module, you must qualify which module
                   'If there is an argument it would be: Call Different_Sub(argument)

NextOffDay = "02/25/2015" 'Change this date to whatever you need, or have a user enter the date through an input box or set it to a certain cell.

For i = 0 to 44
If AFPSECONDOFFDAY(NextOffDay + i) <> "" then
    Thisworkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1,columns.count).end(xltoleft).offset(0,1) = AFPSECONDOFFDAY(NextOffDay + i)
End if
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: The sub procedure doesn't work flexibly and it returns date from 1900s. Can you insert loop inside functions? What I hope is that the function being able to return only the dates that are either Monday, Wednesday or Saturday in the next 45 days. Anyways, thanks for the effort!

Comment: I see the problem in the code I posted above and can fix the date issue. The loop can go inside of the function, but then it will return a long string in one cell, is that what you want?

Comment: I like your idea of using inputbox. Can it have each date in one cell? Can you teach me how to write the recognise empty cells and delete the column? Thank you!

Comment: If you want it to write each to it's own cell, you will need to use a sub procedure like I posted above. Also, if you want to have it remove empty cells, you will need to use a sub procedure. If you would like to recognize and delete empty cells, you will need to give more information about the structure of the workbook.  I'm now confused why the above code would give you dates in the 1900s. I tested the loop in the code and it produces the desired dates.

Comment: your answer and comments are a useful learning guide! I think I can play around with the code to make it work. Didn't know that you have to use sub procedure to do that. Two last question: "can I call sub procedure in a function?" "Can you add on to the code to show how you call another sub procedure in a sub procedure?" Thanks!

Comment: You can call a function from a sub procedure, but not the other way around. I'll edit the code above to call another sub procedure.